# Prove covariance between sample value and sample mean

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I'm trying to figure out how to prove that:

$$\mathbb{Cov}(Y_i, \bar{Y}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n},$$

and then use it to show that sample variance is an unbiased estimator.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $Y_1, ..., Y_n$ is an iid sample

$$ cov(\overline{Y}, Y_i) 
= cov(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} Y_k, Y_i) 
= \frac{1}{n} cov(\sum_{k=1}^{n} Y_k, Y_i) 
= \frac{1}{n} cov(Y_i, Y_i)  = var(Y_i)/n 
$$

because all of the other covariances are zero.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming iid $Y_1,...,Y_n$

$\mathbb{Cov}(Y_i, \bar{Y}) = \mathbb{E}(Y_i\bar{Y})-\mathbb{E}(Y_i)\mathbb{E}(\bar{Y})$

$\mathbb{E}(Y_i \bar{Y})=(1/n)\mathbb{E}( Y_i^2 + \sum_{j \neq i}Y_iY_j)=\sigma^2/n + \mu^2$

$\mathbb{E}(Y_i)\mathbb{E}(\bar{Y}) =\mu^2$